# Count down stop at 0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, intervals

Trying to create a simple countdown but i want it to stop once the timer reaches 0 .. I dont know how to implement it though.

```
function myButton($interval) {
    return {
        templateUrl: '/templates/myButton.html',
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: { },
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
            scope.workTime = 3;
            scope.buttonText = "Start";

            var timeSet;

            scope.countdown = function() {
                scope.workTime--;
            }
            scope.startTimer = function() {
                 if(scope.buttonText == "Reset") {
                     scope.workTime = 3;
                     $interval.cancel(timeSet);
                     scope.buttonText = "Start";
                     console.log( "test restarted");

                 } else {
                     timeSet = $interval(scope.countdown,1000);
                     scope.buttonText = "Reset";
                     console.log("test started");
                 }
            }
        }
    }

};


<div>
    <h1>{{ workTime}}</h1>
    <button ng-click="startTimer()">{{buttonText}}</button>
<div>
```

I've tried an if statement :

```
if (scope.workTimer === 0 ) {
$interval.cancel(timeSet);
}
```

but the timer keeps going into the negative digits. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the condition for 0 value in the scope.countdown

```
scope.countdown = function() {

      if(scope.workTime === 0)
      {
         $interval.cancel(timeSet);
      }
      else
      {
         scope.workTime--;
      }
  }
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/uziM32Ctcb80p15HZuFd?p=preview